# Compiling SUNDANCE 4.73 with gcc 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, 64-bit, sundance

This might sound something very basic/naive.. but its been ages since I have been with C/C++ and feel lost with this..

I am busy getting started with opinionfinder, which requires me to get SUNDANCE 4.3.7.  Getting to compile SUNDANCE is proving to be a bigger effort than i thought.

Following instructions, I launch the install_sundace script, but get this error... Looks like my compiling environment is not properly detected...

Few things I already tried-

1. the install_sundance script uses c-shell. As a test, In installed C shell and tried to see if I can still get my C compilation environment fine.  That works fine.
2. I tried writing a basic program which uses at least one library other than stdio, and it works (I tried Strings.h)

The error message that I am getting - 
Command being run -

```
g++ -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pipe -g -static -I../include -DHOME=\"/media/misc/development/opinionfinder/software/sundance-4.37/\" -c -fPIC -o shared/activation.o activation.C
```

And the error message -

```
In file included from nlptypes.h:16:0,
                 from activation.h:46,
                 from activation.C:26:
../include/sunstr.h: In constructor ‘sunstr::SRef::SRef(const char*)’:
../include/sunstr.h:99:21: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
../include/sunstr.h:102:20: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
../include/sunstr.h: In member function ‘void sunstr::SRef::Assign(const char*)’:
../include/sunstr.h:131:26: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
../include/sunstr.h:136:19: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: I'm in this situation too. I want install openfinder, but by following the steps in the installation README Sundance v.4.3.7. I found your same error. I read your answer Jonatahn, and don't know how to implement it.
Could you solve that? Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: There are a few more tweaks needed on the code. There is a tutorial here: http://www.christopia.net/2011/10/21/installing-and-running-opinion-finder-for-sentiment-analysis Note, it will only compile on 32 bit systems, the code seems not to be prepared for 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, there appears to be a missing `#include <string.h>` or `#include <cstring>` in the `sunstr.h` header.

With `<cstring>`, you'd need some `using` clauses too - one for each of the two functions.

You do not add a `using namespace std;` clause to a header.